# Correlation between 2 different json file with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Is it possible with jq to find a correlation between 2 different json file? I have 2 files where both of the same ID key with different pieces of information.

File1

```
{
  "id": 3918389,
  "name": "Application",
  "servers": 5566625
}
```

File2

```
{
  "ServerID": 5566625,
  "AccountID": 661737,
  "HostName": "example.com",

}
```

I want a file where "ServerID" and "servers" is the same then merge all info like this:

Output

```
{
"id": 3918389,
"name": "Application",
"AccountID": 661737,
"HostName": "example.com",
}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***jq*** solution:

```
cat File[1-2] | jq -s 'if .[0].servers == .[1].ServerID then 
              .[0] + .[1] | del(.servers,.ServerID)  else "not match" end'
```

The output:

```
{
  "id": 3918389,
  "name": "Application",
  "AccountID": 661737,
  "HostName": "example.com"
}
```

---

Details:

- `cat File[1-2]` - concatenates and send to the standard output contents of `File1` and `File2` sequentially
- `-s` (`--slurp`) - instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once.
- `if-then-else` - condition, performs merging of 2 objects `.[0] + .[1]` along with deleting the compared keys `del(.servers,.ServerID)` if crucial properties are equal `.[0].servers == .[1].ServerID`, otherwise - prints `not match`

Comment: Thank you, it really works!
I practicing jq now, and I wonder if my File1 would contain more "servers" with the same "name", can I collect all the hostname for the "ServerID", is still possible with jq?
Pastebin example included.

https://pastebin.com/wBWgJ6da

Thanks again!

Comment: @TökiMivan, it's good to create a new question for new conditions